# A locally-stored version of something like Google IO's conference map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, openstreetmap

There is a beautiful "Interactive Conference Map" for Google IO 2010 here:
http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/map/#level1

Notice the overlays and useful layout. It works well on mobile devices too.

I want to do the same thing, but instead of GMaps loading new tiles every time it is panned or zoomed, I want to have all the tiles pre-cached. This also means it wouldn't need data connection.

Someone told me it was against GMaps Terms of Service to pre-cache the tiles, but have been unable to find out for sure. If it IS against their terms of service, I wonder if there is another way (another service) someone has found, e.g. using OpenStreetMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing your own tile overlay, then you can certainly cache **your** tiles.  It's probably a bad idea to cache Google's tiles, though.  See [How to cache Google map tiles for offline usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage/6183453#6183453) for some details and also some links to projects that are trying to make it possible to do this anyway.

Comment: Great link, and thanks for the advice, very helpful. Can't vote it up yet cos I don't have 15 reputation though..

Comment: Heh, not sure if you were slyly asking for the question to be voted up so you could have enough rep to upvote, but uh, it worked.  :-)

Comment: Well... I didn't think of that but won't say no. And now I can vote your answer up as it deserves to be..