# Android Google Map API Not provides Any Classes/Methods to manage maps tiles

Tags: android, google-maps

In google Map API Documentation they wrote :

> Tiles are cached on the filesystem in your application's directory.
>   The cache is auto-managed so you don't need to do anything with it,
>   and can delete it at any time.

Here i want to know Technical Reasons Why android google map api not proveds any classes/methods to manage map tiles in cache and we can use in offline mode.

If there is no Methods and Classes for this So how Google Maps Application Do Precache Map Area Feature.?

Please Any body explain me in technical terms why they don't provides this thing in their API classes or methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I know its not possible with google maps and its a violation of their terms of service if you did it somehow (link: [How to cache Google map tiles for offline usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage)) (PLEASE correct me if I'm wrong).

But from what I've read you should just look into alternatives to google maps... Heres another link: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=20097090