# Offline Google Maps in an Android app

Tags: google-maps

Recently Google released a new version of their Google Maps which lets you save an offline version of a particular chunk of the map. At the same time I've been playing around with making an Android app which uses the Google Maps API, and I was just wondering... is it possible in some way to get that offline map and get my application to use it? So that my application doesn't need an internet connection either?

I'm aware that OpenStreetMap is an alternative but I don't think it'll work with the project I have in mind.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

that may be a violation of Google's Terms of Service.
Have a look at this: [How to cache Google map tiles for offline usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage)