# Use Google Map in iPhone app created through PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, google-maps, cordova

I need some guidance in matter of using `Google map` in creating iPhone app that is i m creating through `Phonegap`. 
I have heard that Google maps can be used without internet connection by using `Google map API`.

```
My question is how to apply that functionality?
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps api can not be used offline due to the terms of service. 
If you cache the tiles it will be a terms violation. It can be done if you purchase the enterprise edition. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage) for more information on the subject. You might have to use something else if you absolutely must have that functionality.

You should check out openlayers. That might be of help.