# How to re-render html element in canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, canvas, html5-canvas

I have short question.

Is possible render Google maps or Bing maps to hidden element and re-render in canvas with sepia and blur effect?

I think not, so, is possible do this with any kind of todays technologie?

Comment: Like an instagram version of Google Maps? That's pure evil man.

Comment: My idea is simle: I just want find user's city on map by location and render this city as background of page/element (in sepia/grayscale and blur effect)... :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to render the maps to a hidden element and then capture it somehow, the maps are all made of images anyway, you just need to download the image tiles.  You can then add those images to a canvas in the normal way.

However, downloading and storing GMaps images would [probably be a violation of their terms of service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6109369/8655), I imagine Bing will have similar restrictions.  However OpenStreetMap [does allow tile downloading](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy), if you scroll to the bottom of that page you'll see some links to tile providers and tools.