# Everything about Map

Tags: android, google-maps, offline-caching

I am new in android programming. I want to know about GPS. I searched and i know a little about this. anyway, i want to use Map, before i used `com.google.android.maps.MapView` in my project but now i want to know everything about Map.What are ways for using map in project except above way? Can i use `com.google.android.maps.MapView` in my project but i dont connect to internet? I mean what are ways for showing map and searching on map with offline way?

I searched but i cant get answer of full of my questions :(
Thanks for advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start on Google maps, You can refer this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start also MapView is deprecated now, so You have to move with Google Map Version 2.

Example Code : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/
All the Best..

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. you mean, Can i use MapView with offline mode and online mode?I read this link and i think, i use another way for offline mode! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage

Comment: I am not very sure about offline mode of map.. let me search

Answer (score 0):

You should use Fragment. It is like that on layout;

```
<fragment
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
   android:id="@+id/myMapView"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:clickable="true" />
```

To use that you should add **google-play-services_lib** project to your project build path.
Then in your class you should implement FragmentActivity like that;

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity{

private GoogleMap mMap;

UiSettings settings;
MapController mapController;
GeoPoint geopoint;
RectF oval;
Canvas canvas;
int mRadius = 5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUpMap();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    setUpMap();
}

private void setUpMap(){
    if (mMap != null) {
        return;
    }
    mMap=((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myMapView)).getMap();
    if (mMap == null) {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place1, 15));
    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);           

}
```

You should obtain an apikey for google maps from this [link](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) or you can continue step by step from this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Add your apikey and permissions to Manifest file like that;

```
<uses-permission android:name="your_package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
       android:value="your_api_key"/>
```

Note: meta-data must be inside of **application** in your manifest.

Comment: Thanks @Droid. but when i use GoogleMap, should i use "INTERNET"? becuase you use internet permissioin in Manifest file. I confused. please tell me what are ways for showing map in offline mode in android?

Comment: and another thing, for using GoogleMap, i should use Fragment? Can i use a thing like "MapView" in my layout? Thanks

Comment: I don't know about offline mapping. Google Maps Api uses both gps and internet connection. Because of this, i added Internet permission. Then in my opinion the easiest way of using google maps v2 api that using fragment.