# How to cache/download google map v2 tile programmatically?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, osmdroid, offline-caching, google-maps-engine

How to cache/download google map v2  tile programmatically?, is it possible?

Bcos according to this [prntscr.com/3cyiqf](http://prntscr.com/3cyiqf) its not possible but as I have seen this link 
[TileProvider using local tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784841/tileprovider-using-local-tiles)
I thought that if Android provides TileProvider class to load/use tile from the asset than it should be something available for caching/downloading a tile programmatically/run time

**My Actual requirement is :**

If user is connected with internet at that time he can able to download/cache a tile of specific area or he can download/cache, visible map in the phone screen only and whenever he goes offline at that time downloaded map should goes to be visible.

**What I have done up till now:**

I have seen OSMDROID lib they provide very good functionality but issue is I want to use Google Map V2 only

I have already checked Static Map API and I have also created one demo for downloading a tile but they return an image with specified zoom level  so in that case if I use static map api than user can see only 1 level of map they can’t able to zoom-in/out so that’s not good.

**Conclusion  :**

I want to know is Google Map V2 provide  any facility to download/cache a map tiles programmatically/run time?

**EDIT**

Can i use Google Map Engine for the same?

Comment: As going through your requirements nutiteq SDK will be best suitable for you

Comment: There is an official support for Google Maps offline (if I'm not mistaken), but doing otherwise would be a violation of terms (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: @jyomin, nutiteq sdk didn't use google map :(

Comment: @shkschneider, i'm confused can you please explain it more

Comment: @Rajan I just think "How to cache/download google map v2 tile programmatically?" is not allowed by Google Maps terms of service. Someone confirms?

Comment: Exactly I am also agree with @shkschneider. One way is You can make open the inbuilt google maps from your app instead opening GMaps in your activity. In this way you have given controls to the GMapsApplication & you can store the offline maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) 10.1.3(b) you can do it temporally on mobile device.

This [project](http://code.google.com/p/robertprojects/) implement it, I can't provide particular example but you can dig in into it coz it open-source.

Comment: Looks like they have moved the relevant portion of the agreement to 10.5(d).  In case someone is looking for it.   Also the project has moved from Google code to GitHub:   https://github.com/RobertDeveloper/RMaps.0.9.x

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing) link I understand that you must have licence for what you want. At the bottom of the page says

> You can license Google Maps as an embedded feature of your stand-alone software or device

Google provides you a lot of free services, but most of all have a limit and after that limit you must pay that service.

Comment: But in license also they didn't mention anything about offline map functionality

Comment: @Rajan you can simply send a mail to google maps staff and put them your question, but from google website I understand that they don't provide this service, in specialy not for free and for small apps.

Comment: And? Any answer from them?

Comment: No, finally i decide to d/w map tiles and load it on MapView whenever user in offline mode, In my case i want only one city's map so it's convenient for me.

Comment: After having lots of searching for my task I decided to send a mail to google for offline maps related help, can anyone text me the proper email to whom address ?

Comment: Any luck regarding this? Can we use programmatically to download tiles in android