# Avoid reloading google map tiles

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a relatively simple web application that cycles through a few points on the map using the "panTo()" function, and it is causing me problems.

The app itself works fine, but after it is left running for a couple hours, Google starts blocking my requests (I think it suspects that I might be harvesting its maps). The app is intended to be looping through the data all day long, so it's important it works for an extended period of time.

Any way to load the tiles just once, and prevent subsequent re-loads of the same tiles when panning around?

Comment: What else does your application do(I guess it's not simply panning around ). What will be  blocked...the loading of the tiles?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage

Comment: @Dr. Molle. It actually is just panning around. It's going to be used as more of a fun display showing facts about countries participating in the FIFA World Cup. The issue is that Google starts eventually blocking the map tiles. There are other parts of the app, but they do no utilize Google's services

Comment: I was running a self-panning map now for more than 8 hours, the tiles still will be loaded. Are you sure that google blocks it, maybe there is an issue with your browser/environment.

Comment: I am sure Google was blocking it. The web console showing Google's reponse as '503' errors, with links to a captcha page (which didnt help once completed)