# Can we cache google map programmatically?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Few days ago I search information how to cache google map programmatically. Google map api doesn't provide api to cache google map. I saw TOS https://developers.google.com/maps/terms
Do I understand correctly?

I got requirement to show map offline. OSM is the way I can use instead. Is it the right way?
But yesterday I found the app  "new my Maps" can cache google map.

This app is on apple store. **How does this app cache map for offline?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cache Google map tiles for offline usage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage)

Comment: Hi check this blog may help ur requirement http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/01/31/deconstructing-the-map-cache-tiling-scheme-part-ii-working-with-map-caches-programmatically/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hieyy Kingkan Banyenngam

This link may right solution for your problem:-

[Check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847353/use-google-maps-offline-in-an-app)

Please let me know if it didn't work.

Spartacus:- Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide an answer along with your link. Links can get broken

Comment: in fact it has been removed

Answer (score 2):

This [blog](http://datamoil.blogspot.com/2011/05/offline-google-maps-on-osmdroid.html) cache google tiles and display by osmdroid

Comment: Caching of google Map tiles is still illegal, right?