# Using Google Maps offline (Js Api)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make an NodeJs App in which, on web page I'm using Maps, For some reasons I've chosen **Google Maps** and I want to stick to it. My question is, Is there anyway where I can either store or cache map tiles offline and later on use it as needed [Note: Not looking for *any hack or Illegal* way for it, I already know there are many such ways].

I tried and saw many options like GEE (Google Earth Enterprise) portable but I guess they are shutting it down very soon i.e by 2017.

Basically what I'm trying here is to minimize the data usage on rendering map tiles, so alternatively, if there ain't a way to make google map work offline any suggestion or advice for minimizing data usage is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Map offline in web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839377/google-map-offline-in-web-application)

Comment: @xomena please read question again it's not duplicate anyhow

Answer (score 17):

The offline access via Maps JavaScript API is not available at the moment. There is a feature request in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827808

Please star this feature request to express your interest and receive further updates from Google.

Answer (score 0):

1.Use Localstorage instead it might help but will be used in google chrome.
2.Check this url it might help [How to cache Google map tiles for offline usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage)

Comment: as mentioned in my question I'm looking for reliable and legal way of doing that. I already have checked __gmapcatcher__ and I don't think it is legal, and for other option I would like to stick with Google Maps only.

Comment: ok fine i want you to check this website http://offline-map.appspot.com/ and kindly check https://github.com/tbicr/OfflineMap  this might help