# how to make maps work offline in google maps api for android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I am totally new to this api and I was wondering if there is a way that I can use the maps offline. I don't mind the size of the application be large so if there are anyways involved caching or something else size related, it is not a problem

Any suggestions?

ps: if it is not possible in google's api,is there a way to do this with another api form another source which provides a mapping service?

Comment: Duplicate of the following - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage And/Or of this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235835/using-google-maps-offline-js-api

Comment: This is what i was trying for last 6 month. nothing found yet. google strictly denies for it in its terms . and you dont have a way around. use osmdroid . this should come handy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) to work offline with Google Maps. Osmdroid is a replacement for Android's MapView class. It also includes a modular tile provider system with support for numerous online and offline tile sources and overlay support with built-in overlays for plotting icons, tracking location, and drawing shapes.

You can follow this [tutorial](http://datamoil.blogspot.com/2011/05/offline-google-maps-on-osmdroid.html) in how to use it.