# How to download specific region of google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, offline-mode

I am making an android application that will show google map on the screen. By clicking on a button user can download a the his/her specific region and store that in internal storage. Later when internet connection is poor or not available then user can use the offline map downloaded earlier. How to make this kind of app. Please guide me.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should carefully read [Google Maps APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) especially 10.5 (d) and 10.5 (e), because technically you can (temporary) download tiles for specific region from Google Maps server via series of URLs like http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x=95&y=55&z=7 and then create custom tile provider for Google Maps like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14833256/6950238) answer of [Alex Vasilkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687154/alex-vasilkov). Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36636801/6950238) answer of [KENdi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5996134/kendi).

Comment: Ok I will check.

Comment: @Andrii Omelchenko but how to get tile of a specific latitude longitude location?

Comment: @has19 Take a look at [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start).

Comment: @andriiOmelchenko can u check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539634/google-map-get-all-tiles-locations-at-a-specific-location