# Google Map offline in web application

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to download all the images in google map to avail the offline access forever in the web application?

I can able to perform the online operations using

```
src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"
```

but I need Offline access forever by downloading everything once in online.

Comment: IMHO it is nearly impossible to download the whole world cache, it will be a lot of Gigabytes od data even for one small country, not the whole world.

Comment: yaeh it goes more than 4 TB. Is there anyways to achieve it?  zoom 3x is even enough.

Answer (score 9):

I am afraid the solution that you try to implement is against of the terms of service. Please refer to paragraphs 10.1 (a):

> **No access to APIs or Content except through the Service**. You will not access the Maps API(s) or the Content except through the Service. For example, you must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s).

and 10.5 (d) of ToS:

> **No caching or storage**. You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content to be used outside the Service, except that you may store limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation due to network latency (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from accurately tracking usage), and only if such storage:
>   is temporary (and in no event more than 30 calendar days);
>   is secure;
>   does not manipulate or aggregate any part of the Content or Service; and
>   does not modify attribution in any way.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions

The offline access via Maps JavaScript API is not available at the moment. There is a feature request in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827808

Please star this feature request to express your interest and receive further updates from Google.