# Download programmatically on Google Maps an offline area

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to know if there is a way to make my Android app trigger the download of an offline area in Google Maps app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cache Google map tiles for offline usage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage)

Comment: I've checked previous topics in this matter but most of then were quite old and/or talk about a home made solution for cache tiles or something like that. What I want here is to make use,  programmatically, of the Google Maps offline capabilites that were introduced into Maps just a few months ago.

Comment: @Mauricio Resis are you able to download

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is.

click the menu at the left side of the blank, choose 'offline map', you can choose the scope/granularity of the map.

If you are open to use other map services, I recommend to use HERE map, it can even calculate path without internet connection.

Comment: The problem is that I have to find a programmatically way to do that on maps. Do this through user interface is not what I need. Btw, thanks for the HERE map idea, as last resource, we will migrate to this map.