# Download google map areas and display while offline in android app

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, offlineapps

In my android app there are list of city with there geo location. When user in online then list of city display and app store all data in local db.
Is this possible to display google map of that city when user went offline, So i can display list of city and if user click on any city then app can display google map of that city.

I have no idea about this, searched a lot but nothing found related to it.

If any one of you have idea about it please provide me some suggestions.

TIA

Comment: I am  not sure why some one marked this question as off topic. This is related to development question. I am facing problem in download google map in my android app this is my actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage).
There is information about enterprise Maps API. You can pay for it.
And also you can check some other services like Google maps with offline access.

http://code.google.com/p/ogmaps/

http://code.google.com/p/gmapoffline/

Hope it's helped.