# Download map to use offline

Tags: android, google-maps, offline-caching

I am developing an Android app using Google Maps API, and I want to know if I can download or cache the part of map that the user is watching to use it offline.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cache Google map tiles for offline usage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for precaching Google Maps. And also it is illegal .If you want to use precaching , you can go for Open Street Maps and other open alternatives  .