# Save programmatically (via API) created map to Google Drive (.gmap)

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I've programmatically created a google map in Android using the Google Map API / MapFragment. I'd like to be able to save this map on my Google Drive (just like you would if you used the native Google Maps android App or the web site - [either of these would create a .gmap link file linking to some data somewhere).  Does anyone know how to do this?  Basically a "Save My Map to Google Drive" option.

Note: I don't want to save a screen shot.

Comment: Would you consider saving the 'metadata' as JSON? You could then recreate the map with the same API. Either that, or save the HTML? Sadly, Google may not approve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage

Comment: I guess that's an option but i was looking for a way to replicate what the native apps do once you've created a map. I.e create it and save it on Google drive.

Comment: I haven't perused the docs or the license agreement, but a cursory glance at some other SO questions leaves me with the impression that you can't do that without paying. Best of luck anyhow.