# Map not loading when internet turned off android native/ java

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Google maps in android native application is showing blank screen when internet is turned off, Although map is loading/working correctly when internet is turned ON.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Maps needs an internet connection, at least to do certain things.  Anyway, most likely your app won't work completely if the internet connection is turned off, so I wouldn't waste time thinking about this.

Comment: that is expected behavior. It should be that way, as maps work only online

Comment: I totally agree with you, but I have noticed sometimes occasionally it works without internet connection

Comment: If you want to support offline catch then you need to purchase Google Maps API for standard use, here is the tow link which explain you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage
 https://enterprise.google.com/maps/terms/us/maps_purchase_agreement.html

Comment: Nice suggestion although, Basically my field officer visits different locations to save offline data with location of destination, I just wanted to show his location on map before saving data into local database to make sure He got the correct destination location. However sometimes He doesn't have internet connection