# use google maps android offline programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, google-maps

I want to programmatically store a part of Google Map for offline use in my app.
This feature is in Google Maps app, but I didn't know how to add it in my app

Comment: The last I checked. That would void the google maps api EULA. I suggest using openstreetmap.org if you want to use offline maps.

Comment: So I can't use Google Maps offline due to usage restrictions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage